# opengl drawing multipe objects from one vao

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

i have a single vao that contains a character set of a font.
Each character is drawn with a set of indices belonging to it.
The idea was to write a couple of chars and bind the vao only one time.

Everything works fine - except the positioning of the glyphs.
The loop is like

```
glGetUniformLocations()
glBindVertexArray( vao )
for( i=0; i< lg; i++ )
{
  glUniforMatrix4fV();      // send translation matrix to shader
  glDrawElements( part of the indexbuffer );
  trans_mx = glm::translate();  // compute the translation matrix
}
```

Vertexshader is:

```
#version 450 core

layout( location = 0 ) in vec3 vx;          // the vertex_buffer in modelspace
layout( location = 1 ) in vec4 vx_col;      // color of each vertex

out vec4 fragment_color;                   

uniform mat4  mvp_mx;         
uniform mat4  trans_mx;         

void main()
{
  gl_Position = mvp_mx * vec4( trans_mx * vec4( vx, 1.0f ) );

  fragment_color = vx_col;
}
```

The translation works - but not between the draw calls.
All chars are drawn at the same position. which is translated.
For me it seems as if the translation matrix will not be updated.
??????

this is the code from the function that draws the chars

```
  lg  = strlen( str );
  vao = sfs->vao;
  _sys.mvp_mx   = _sys.proj_mx * _sys.view_mx * vao->model_mx;   // compute global mvp


  sh_s = &__sh_list[ vao->shd_ind ];       // pointer to our shader_struct
  sh_s->get_uniform_loc();                 // get uniform locations for this shader
  glBindVertexArray( vao->id );            // bind vao

  glUseProgram( sh_s->prg_id );            // use the shader

  for(  c1 = 0; c1 < lg; c1++ )
  {
    sh_s->send_uniform();                    // send uniforms to the shader
    i_seg = &vao->ind_b->seg[ str[ c1 ] ];   // segment for this character
    glDrawElements( i_seg->prim, i_seg->count, i_seg->type, ( void* )i_seg->offset );
    _sys.trans_mx = glm::translate( glm::mat4( 1.0f ), glm::vec3( 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) );     
  }

  glBindVertexArray( 0 );           // unbind vao
  glUseProgram( 0 );                // unbind shader
```

Comment: you dont send trans_mx to shader, do it before drawing elements

Comment: @rabbid the translation matrix has a glm::mat4( 1.0f ) when entering the loop. After the first itration of the loop i recalculate it and send it to the shader. The effect is that the 2 chars i want to draw at different positions, they are drawn at the same position - the translated one.

Comment: @angen - the code is just pseudo. The first call of glUniformMatrix4fv() before the drawing call sends the precalculated translation matrix to the shader -> glm::mat4( 1.0f ). So the first char should be drawn at initial position, then i recalculate the matrix, send it again and the socond char should be moved to the side. But actually both were drawn on the translated position. ???

Comment: so actually you compute for each model trans_mx before glUniformMatrix4fv and not after drawing as your post says? if yes, correct your post pls

Comment: I think we really need to see your sending matrices to shader and how you compute them

Comment: I have copied my code in the main part of the question.
The vao contains 128 segments of the index buffer - the index of the segments has the same index as the char i want to write
sh_s->getuniform_loc is a function pointer to a function that sends all required uniforms to the shaders.
So the loop is
1. sending uniforms
2. getting pointer to the segments with the indices for this char
3. drawing the char
4. updating the translation matrix to next char position, there is a variable missing for longer literals
and again

Comment: @rabbid - yes you are right. I try with 2 character at the moment and just wanted to see if they are moved from one another.
You matrix calculation will be the final step..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
for(  c1 = 0; c1 < lg; c1++ )
{
    .....
    _sys.trans_mx = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
}
```

will ongoing calculate the same matrix.

If you want to calculate a continuously changing matrix in the loop, then you have to continually change the matrix based on its current value:

```
for(  c1 = 0; c1 < lg; c1++ )
{
    .....
    _sys.trans_mx = glm::translate(_sys.trans_mx, glm::vec3(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
}
```

Or you calculate the matrix dependent on the control variable of the loop

```
for(  c1 = 0; c1 < lg; c1++ )
{
    .....
    _sys.trans_mx = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(10.0f * c1, 0.0f, 0.0f));
}
```

Comment: this works
_sys.trans_mx = glm::translate( glm::mat4( 1.0f ), glm::vec3( 10.0f * c1, 0.0f, 0.0f ) );

it is the same as with cpus - more than one brain shortens the solution time